# low priority and high priority implicits in scala

Tags: scala, implicit

In following code from Scala's puzzlers, it seems that there is no conflict in implicits because `TestAlarmHandler` is more specific. I didn't understand the explanation though. Why is `TestAlarmHandler` is more specific than `DefaultAlarmHandler`?

```
object Scanner {
  trait Console { def display(item: String) }
  trait AlarmHandler extends (() => Unit)
  def scanItem(item: String)(implicit c: Console) {
    c.display(item)
  }
  def hitAlarmButton()(implicit ah: AlarmHandler) { ah() }
}


class OperatingMode {
  implicit val ConsoleRenderer = new Scanner.Console {
    def display(item: String) { println(s"Found a ${item}") }
  }
  implicit val DefaultAlarmHandler = new Scanner.AlarmHandler {
    def apply() { println("ALARM! ALARM!") }
  }
}
object NormalMode extends OperatingMode
object TestMode extends OperatingMode {
  override implicit val ConsoleRenderer = new Scanner.Console {
    def display(item: String) { println("Found a detonator") }
  }
  implicit val TestAlarmHandler = new Scanner.AlarmHandler {
    def apply() { println("Test successful. Well done!") }
  }
}
import NormalMode._
scala> Scanner scanItem "knife"
Found a knife
scala> Scanner.hitAlarmButton()
ALARM! ALARM!
import TestMode._
scala> Scanner scanItem "shoe"
Found a detonator
scala> Scanner.hitAlarmButton()
Test successful. Well done!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TestAlarmHandler` is more specific than `DefaultAlaramHandler` because `TestAlarmHandler` is defined in an anonymous class which is derived from class `OperatingMode` defining `DefaultAlarmHandler`.

---

Formally, [the Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html#implicit-parameters) specifies how to handle a case when more than one eligible arguments are found, as follows (note that both `TestAlarmHandler` and `DefaultAlarmHandler` are eligible because they have been imported by `import TestMode._`):

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit parameter's type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules of static overloading resolution.

Section [6.26.3 Overloading Resolution](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution) defines the concept of being *more specific* in terms of the concept of *relative weight*:

> The *relative weight* of an alternative A over an alternative B is a number from 0 to 2, defined as the sum of
>
> - 1 if A is as specific as B, 0 otherwise, and
> - **1 if A is defined in a class or object which is derived from the class or object defining B, 0 otherwise.**

The relative weight of `TestAlarmHandler` over `DefaultAlarmHandler` is 1 while that of `DefaultAlarmHandler` over `TestAlarmHandler` is 0. Note that `TestAlarmHandler` is defined in an anonymous class which is derived from class `OperatingMode` defining `DefaultAlarmHandler`. The first rule is of concern when resolving method overloading, but not relevant here.

> An alternative A is *more specific* than an alternative B if the relative weight of A over B is greater than the relative weight of B over A.

`TestAlarmHandler` is more specific than `DefaultAlaramHandler` because the relative weight `TestAlarmHandler` over `DefaultAlarmHandler` is greater than that of the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

That's because TestMode is subclass of OperationMode, and scala at first look for implicits in scope of TestMode and only if not found it will lookup up in hierarchy.