# Implicit resolution in Scala when more than 1 instance is available

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following trait:

```
trait Close[T]{
  def close(t: T): Unit
}
object Close {
    final class CloseOps[T](t: T, c: Close[T]){
      def close(): Unit = c.close(t)
    }
    implicit def toCloseOps[T](t: T)(implicit c: Close[T]) = new CloseOps[T](t, c)
}
```

And its instances:

```
implicit val closeInputStream: Close[InputStream] = (t: InputStream) => t.close()
implicit def noOpClose[T]: Close[T] = _ => ()
```

My misunderstanding is if I import both of the `implicit`s listed above I have the more specific one is used. I mean the method

```
def someMethod[T](t: T)(implicit c: Close[T]){
    t.close()
}
```

and its usage

```
import Close._

val is: InputStream = new InputStream{
    override def read() = -1
    override def close() = throw new RuntimeException()
}

someMethod(is) //throws RuntimeException
```

So is it reliable to assume that in such a case the instance of `closeInputStream` instance will be used instead of `noOpClose[InputStream]`? Or is it common to provide sort of fallback implicit instance? Both of them are matched.

Comment: Take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339575/low-priority-and-high-priority-implicits-in-scala. Maybe it ca help

Comment: Is `someMethod()` correct? You haven't proven, to the compiler's satisfaction, that type `T` actually _has_ a `close()` member method, only that an implicit `Close[T]` is in scope. But that doesn't do much good since you don't do anything with it, so it really doesn't matter, in this case, which implicit is found since it's unused.

Comment: @jwvh Also implicit conversions. I mean all `typeclass` boilerplate is imported so `close` can be used.

Comment: Just because a `Close[X]` exists, and is in scope, doesn't mean that you can then invoke `.close()` on an instance of type `X`. So `t.close()` won't compile but `c.close(t)` will compile and throw the RuntimeException you've described, which is why I asked if you've posted the intended `someMethod()` code.